# Construct a list of wpf Hyperlink elements from an XML source file using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq

I have an xml file like the following:

```
<Links>
    <Link>
        <Text>Google</Text>
        <Uri>http://www.google.com</Uri>
    </Link>
    <Link>
        <Text>Yahoo</Text>
        <Uri>http://www.yahoo.co.uk</Uri>
    </Link>
</Links>
```

From it, I'd like to build a bunch of Hyperlink elements containing

- Display text
- A URI
- A method to navigate to the URI

Obviously, there's a number of ways of going about this, and historically, I'd probably do something like this:

```
List<ACMEXmlNode> nodes = ACMEXmlParser.GetNodes("Link", targetDoc);
List<Hyperlink>;
foreach (var node in nodes) {
    var currentLink = new Hyperlink();
    currentLink.Uri = node.ChildNode("Uri").Value;

    // Can't work out how to do the below line in a linq statement
    currentLink.ContentStart.InsertTextInRun(node.ChildNode("Text").Value);

    currentLink.RequestNavigate += this.DoBrowserNavigate;
}
```

However, I'm also trying to learn Linq, and this seems like it should be a typical use-case for it. Can anyone help me with how to accomplish the same kind of thing with it? Thus far, I have:

```
_Links = new List<Hyperlink>(
                        from linkElement in oLinksConfig.Descendants("Links")
                        select new Hyperlink
                            {
                                NavigateUri = new System.Uri(linkElement.Element("Uri").Value ),

                                // Fails...
                                ContentStart.InsertTextInRun(linkElement.Element("Text").Value)
                            }
                        ).ToList();
```

Which doesn't work. If anyone can tell me how to fix it so it does, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not with LINQ per se, but with the LINQ syntax you chose and the fact that you have a statement:

```
ContentStart.InsertTextInRun(linkElement.Element("Text").Value)
```

inside an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx) block.

Instead, use something like:

```
var links = oLinksConfig
    .Descendants("Links")
    .Select(
        linkElement =>
        {
            var link = new HyperLink { /* your initializations of properties with setters */ };

            //statements are after you have an instance of the class
            link.ContentStart.InsertTextInRun(linkElement.Element("Text").Value;
            return link;
         })
     .ToList();
```

Comment: That was the syntax I was looking for! This looks like it's done the job for me :). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
_Links = nodes.Select(node => {
             var currentLink = new Hyperlink();
             currentLink.NavigateUri = new Uri(node.Element("Uri").Value);
             currentLink.ContentStart
                        .InsertTextInRun(node.Element("Text").Value);
             currentLink.RequestNavigate += this.DoBrowserNavigate;
             return currentLink;
         }).ToList();
```

If you want the input to be just the plain xml file, try this instead:

```
_Links = oLinksConfig.Descendants("Link")
            .Select(link => {
                  var currentLink = new Hyperlink();
                  currentLink.NavigateUri = new Uri(link.Element("Uri").Value);
                  currentLink.ContentStart
                             .InsertTextInRun(link.Element("Text").Value);
                  currentLink.RequestNavigate += this.DoBrowserNavigate;
                  return currentLink;
             }).ToList();
```